# Does OnlyFans have a no 'extreme fisting' policy in their terms of service?

Tags: internet, sex

YouTuber ADoseOfBuckley recently published [a video](https://youtu.be/meptHAGdUOA?t=399) that discussed censorship and the video subscription service, [OnlyFans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OnlyFans).

At 6m39, he shows what he purports to be an excerpt from the OnlyFans Terms of Service. While he doesn't mention it, the text includes an admonition not to upload content that show, promotes or refers to "extreme fisting" (Caution: Even the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisting) about the sex act may not be safe for work.)

I'm just astounded that an international company needs to have fisting regulations in a TOS. I find the whole thing rather surreal and was wondering how real it is.

Comment: This seems like this would be something that would be very easy to check.

Comment: "international company", "video subscription service" etc. Don't they specialize in some kind of porn or similarly titillating material though? Wikipedia says "The service is used primarily by sex workers who produce pornography".

Comment: @Fizz: Indeed, they do specialise in porn, but the *rest* of that sentence says "but it also hosts the work of other content creators, such as physical fitness experts and musicians." so it is inappropriate to simply call them a porn site. I gave a description based on the first sentence in Wikipedia, but emphasized video because "content" is such a vague term.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's easy enough to get the [ToS for OnlyFans](https://onlyfans.com/terms.html).  It states:

> 5. Do not upload, post, display, or publish Content on OnlyFans that:
>
>    a. shows, includes or refers to:
>
>    i. any individual under 18 years old
>
>    ...
>
>    vi. violence, rape, lack of consent, hypnosis, intoxication, sexual assault, torture,
>    sadomasochistic abuse or hardcore bondage, **extreme fisting**, or genital mutilation;
>
>    vii.  ...

Now, this doesn't specify what "extreme" means but instead implies that it is a well-enough understood term that content producers should know.